# PowerShell Start-Job output

Tags: powershell, console

When I run command `Start-Job {dir}` in PowerShell I get output

```
Id              Name            State      HasMoreData     Location             Command
--              ----            -----      -----------     --------             -------
43              Job43           Running    True            localhost             dir
```

How can I make this job write its output to console?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's handled through the `receive-job` cmdlet.

```
$job = Start-Job { dir }
Receive-Job $job
```

You only get data if `HasMoreData` is true on your `get-job` output. This will return as an array, with one line of text per array-element.

`help about_jobs` will give you quite a bit of detail about how to interact with jobs in general.

Comment: So I try:  

`$job = Start-Job { dir }`  
`Receive-Job $job`  
$job.hasMoreData is true, but output is empty.

Comment: @DmitryFedorkov You seem to be missing `-job $job` in your code-fragment, that's needed. The command `help receive-job -examples` will give you very useful information.

Comment: It does not matter, because argument `-Job` has position 1. My problem turned out in PowerGUI that for some reason does not work correctly. Anyway, thanks for help.